# ReactJS Route to a url with previous search parameters

Tags: reactjs, parameters, react-router, history, react-props

I have a React application built with CRA. I have a login page and then a profile page. The flow is - 
I first land on login page. The url is "www.abc.com/login?myParam=true". When i click on the login button, it goes to profile page. The routing happens with history.push like given below -

```
props.history.push("/profile")
```

Current behavior - I land on the profile page and the url is www.abc.com/profile

Expected behavior - I want to land on the profile page with previous page's search parameter(ie; www.abc.com/profile?myParam=true)

What I have tried - I can push extra param in the props.history.push from login page and catch it in profile page and make necessary changes in the url and that works. The problem here is that the I have to pass extra param every time I want to route(in every component)

What I want - I want make the change at one place, such that every time I do a props.history.push("/some-route") from a page url www.abc.com/this-route?myParam=true, I land on the page www.abc.com/some-route?myParam=true